# Prove $\{(w, w) : w \in W\}$ is a subspace of $V\times V$, with $W$ a subspace of $V$

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Prove $\{(w, w) : w \in W\}$ is a subspace of $V\times V$, with $W$ a subspace of $V$.

I have the idea, but I'm not sure about how to structure my proof:

$V\times V = \{(v_1, v_2): v_1, v_2 \in V\}$

$W$ subset of $V \Longrightarrow \forall w \in W, w\in V$

$w_1, w_2 \in W \Longrightarrow w_1, w_2 \in V$

Thus, $\{(w, w) : w \in W\}$ is a subset of $V\times V$

Is the jump between the second to last, and last line unclear? If so, how might I clarify it? Thanks.

Comment: Most teachers will be happy if you skip showing $W \times W \subset V \times V$, and go straight to showing $W \times W$ is a sub-vector space

Comment: ... that is, you should be concentrating on proving the three necessary and sufficient conditions for proving a subset of a vector space is a subspace. That is, prove it is non-empty (e.g. it contains the $0$ vector), prove it is closed under addition, and prove it is closed under scalar multiplication. The subset requirement (which you proved) is vitally important, but it is not what the exercise is about.